# updating a variable via onClick for a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the below "num" inside my render method by the button pusher. I added an onClick functionality to the button targeting my "num" variable but it isn't running it? I tried to turn it into an arrow function as well but that didn't work. Am I doing something? The "num" const would run and cycle through number generated by the randomPerson method.. this is just a test but want to know what I am doing wrong.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [
      { name: 'test1', num: randomNum()},
      { name: 'test2', num: randomNum()}
    ]
  }

  randomPerson =() =>{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()* this.state.persons.length)
  }

  render(){
    const num = this.randomPerson()
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.num}>Switch Person</button>
        <div>
          <Person name={this.state.persons[num].name} randomNum={this.state.persons[num].num} />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is outputting the ```name``` prop working?

Comment: In `<button onClick={this.num}>Switch Person</button>` the `onClick` does nothing... You need to pass in a function to make it do a thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `onClick` in React expects a function. in your code you passed in the return value of `this.randomPerson` which is not a function.

Try this:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [
      { name: 'test1', num: randomNum()},
      { name: 'test2', num: randomNum()}
    ]
  }

  randomPerson =() =>{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()* this.state.persons.length)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.randomPerson}>Switch Person</button>
        {/* ^-- I changed this and removed the num declaration */}
        <div>
          <Person name={this.state.persons[num].name} randomNum={this.state.persons[num].num} />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But I'm unsure what you're trying to do with the generated new random number from `randomPerson`. I assume you might want to use that number to select a random user. For that you will have to add the generated random number from `randomPerson` into state. Unfortunately I've completely forgotten how to do this in class components... So I did that for you with a functional component below:

```
function App() {
    const randomPerson = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.persons.length);

    const [person, setPerson] = useState([
        { name: 'test1', num: randomNum()},
        { name: 'test2', num: randomNum()}
    ]);
    const [currentPerson, setCurrentPerson] = useState(randomPerson());

    const switchPerson = () => {
        setCurrentPerson(randomPerson());
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={switchPerson}>Switch Person</button>
            <div>
                <Person name={person[currentPerson].name} randomNum={person[currentPerson].num} />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: I believe you'r on the right thought process with the functional component. I am still to new this but I was thinking the constant num will update because it is linked to the this.randomPerson() method which returns a random number based on the length of the persons array in the state. Me thinking, that would return a number in this.state.persons[num].name as a prop. When pressing the button with the onClick, i was expecting every click, it would refresh the const num and that'll run the method, randomPerson in real time.. guess not. still trying!

Comment: The functional component should work for you as is. You can use both functional and class components together

Comment: Thanks Dominik! I'll use that for the time being while I figure out how to implement that way using a class component. I believe in order for the app to update in the window, i'll need to somehow change the state / prop in order for it to work in the class component.